# Performance comparison with V8

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, benchmarking, v8

I'm currently testing multiple cases for parsing lines.

Each line is formatted like that:

```
"dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF=dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF=dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF=dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF"
```

There are a lot of lines of course, and I need to extract the **key**, and the **value**.

The **key** is delimited by the first "=" found.
There is never a "=" char in the key.

The **value** is the rest of string next after the first "=" sign.

So for this exemple the result should be:

```
{
  key: "dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF",
  value: "dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF=dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF=dHdX5jOa7ww9cGsW7jQF"
}
```

From here we can iterate on multiple solutions:

```
// the first one is not very efficient with split splice join method
function first(line) {
  const lineSplit = line.split('='),
        key       = lineSplit[0],
        value     = lineSplit.splice(1, lineSplit.length).join('=');

  return {
    key,
    value
  };
}

// the second one execute only what i want to do
// with built-in String prototype's functions
function optimized(line) {
  const index = line.indexOf("="),
        key   = line.substr(0, index),
        value = line.substr(index + 1, line.length);

  return {
    key,
    value
  };
}

// i tried to code the logic myself
function homemade(line) {
    const len = line.length;
    let value = "", key = "", valued = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const char = line[i];
        if (valued === false) {
            if (char !== '=') {
                key += char;
            } else {
                valued = true;
            }
        } else {
            value += char;
        }
    }

    return {
        key,
        value
    };
}

// and next recode substr and foreach built-in to implemant the same
// function but with homemade substr&foreach
String.prototype.substr2 = function(from, to){
    let str = "";
    for (let i = from; i < to; ++i) {
        str += this[i];
    }
    return str;
};

String.prototype.indexOf2 = function(occ){
    const len = this.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (this[i] === occ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};

function overload(line) {
  const index = line.indexOf2("="),
        key   = line.substr2(0, index),
        value = line.substr2(index + 1, line.length);

  return {
    key,
    value
  };
}
```

And voila the results with jsBench:

[I'm using Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

[image]

You can checkout the results of these functions with your browser [in this jsBench](http://jsben.ch/PKqK9)

I don't understand what is going on. I imagined that cannot be possible since I wrote only the code i needed with native for() and other stuffs like this...

My questions are:

Why the builtin string operations are obviously much faster ?

Why this repeated string concatenation is inneficient ?

Is there an alternative to it ?

Comment: As posted, your code has syntax errors. Those `return` statements should be `return { [key]: value };` The posted JSBench page doesn't work for me; they call come up `NaN`.

Comment: It's not clear what you specific question is. Is there some implementation you feel should perform significantly differently?

Comment: Well, the builtin string operations are obviously much faster than those hand-crafted inefficient repeated string concatenations.

Comment: thank you @Bergi but can you answer why ? And why this loop is inneficient ? I edited the post.

Comment: Because the built-in string operations are calls to native code, reimplementing them in javascript is invariably going to be slower. What happens here is exactly what should happen most of the time if the runtime implementors do their job right  - the 'natural', most straightforward solution is fastest.

Comment: @john Because a substring operation doesn't necessarily require any loop depending on the string representation.

Comment: @john Also it might not be the loop itself that is inefficient, but the repeated `+=` operation.

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations. But why in this [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/sdngjkn) the custom forEach and map are faster than array builtin ?

Comment: @john Those custom implementation are not spec compliant. They omit some crucial details like: optional thisArg, checking for array to actually have the property etc. This is how [spec compliant  implementation should look like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the builtin string operations are obviously much faster ?

Because they are optimized, and use internal implementation tricks that are not available to JavaScript code. For example, they avoid repeated string concatenation by building the result in one go.

> Why this repeated string concatenation is inefficient ?

Because it creates many strings as intermediate results.

> Is there an alternative to it ?

Use the builtin string operations :-)